# Java child knows parent but parent doesn't know their childs

Tags: java

I have a list of objects in Java. For example, this JSON-like pseudo code:

```
[
  {
    username: "u1",
    password: "p1",
    email: "e1",
    parent: null
  },
  {
    username: "u2",
    password: "p2",
    email: "e2",
    parent: (the first object for example)
  },
  {
    username: "u3",
    password: "p3",
    email: "e3",
    parent: (also the first object for example)
  }
]
```

I want a function that organize all the objects in an array like this:

```
[
  {
    {
      username: "u1",
      password: "p1",
      email: "e1",
      parent: null
    },
    [
      {
        username: "u2",
        password: "p2",
        email: "e2",
        parent: (as the parent of u2 is u1 it will be nested inside him)
      },
      {
        username: "u3",
        password: "p3",
        email: "e3",
        parent: (also as the parent of u3 is u1 it will be nested inside him)
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically I want a function that search for all child objects and nest them inside his correspondent parent.

I tried to search in google but I couldn't express myself to him to find what I want. Can someone please give some hint or help on how to do it?

**PS: In this example to be easier to understand I wrote the objects in JSON but they are in java. The object knows his parent by the field "parent" that points to the other object**

Comment: Your data seems to be formatted as JSON. Is your input and output a json-formatted String? Or are you aiming for an object-structure?

Comment: How can we know if the `parent` is pointing to which object? Are we compare all 4 fields (username, password,...) to determine that it is the object `parent` is pointing to?

Comment: In the example to be easier to understand I wrote the objects in JSON but they are in java. The object knows his parent by the field "parent" that points to the other object

Comment: I think a tree is a better data structure for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, this makes it harder to understand or point out places to change. You should put actual code - preferably a [mcve] that shows what your classes actually are, and explain what you want to do with the data structure. My guess would be adding a "children" field to each object would do what you need, but it's hard to say for sure at the moment.

Comment: My problem is that the parent can not see their childs, only the childs know who are their parents.
What I want is a function that chains all objects into just one and in that one "parent" I can see al their childs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8, then you can make use of the code snippet given below:- It is based on `groupingBy` feature from java8 streams. Also used the support of `Optional` to handle the special case of root element with a `null` parent.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user1 = new User("u1", "p1", "e1", null);
        User user2 = new User("u2", "p2", "e2", user1);
        User user3 = new User("u3", "p3", "e3", user1);
        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(user1, user2, user3);

        Collection<List<User>> userGroups = group(users);

        System.out.println(userGroups);
    }

    private static Collection<List<User>> group(List<User> users) {
        Map<Optional<User>, List<User>> userGroups = users.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(user -> Optional.ofNullable(user.getParent()))
                        );

        return userGroups.values();

    }
}

class User {

    String username;
    String password;
    String email;
    User parent;

    public User(String uname, String pword, String email, User parent) {
        this.username = uname;
        this.password = pword;
        this.email = email;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public User getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(User parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (password == null) {
            if (other.password != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
            return false;
        if (username == null) {
            if (other.username != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{username:" + username + ", password:" + password + ", email:" + email + "}";
    }   
}
```

Output would look like as given below:-

```
[[{username:u1, password:p1, email:e1}], [{username:u2, password:p2, email:e2}, {username:u3, password:p3, email:e3}]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to add child field to your java class. Then implement hashCode and equals functions

then try this function

```
static List<Item> mapChild(List<Item> items, Item parent) {
    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item item: items) {
        if (parent == null ? item.parent == null : item.parent != null && item.parent.equals(parent)) {
            item.child.addAll(mapChild(items, item));
            result.add(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But the question he asked is like sorting the JSON based on its parent attribute. How come this will be the answer for that ?

Comment: Sorry i don't undestand well his question before.

Comment: Hey Pierre GAGNON thank you, I did that but how should I call that method and why is parent as a parameter?

Comment: Call the method be passing the array of items and null as parent

Comment: parent is in parameter to recusivly search all it child

Comment: It is giving me null pointer exception at line `parent.child.addAll(mapChild(items, item));`

Comment: ah sorry it's item.child.addAll(mapChild(items, item));

Comment: Now it's giving null pointer exception in `if (parent == null ? item.getParent() == null : item.getParent().equals(parent)) {`

Comment: Yes because some parents are null. I merge the method after testing